# How does AngularJS2 inject dependencies into my component with TypeScript

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I am seeing various versions of how to inject dependencies into my component, some are working for me, others not. So I am wondering, what are the pros and cons, what is the recommended best practice and why are certain ones not working as expected. Here an example:

```
@Component()
@Injectable()
class MyComponent {

  dependency1: Dependency1;

  constructor(dependency2: Dependency2, dependency3: Dependency3) {
    this.dependency2 = dependency2;
  }

  someFunction() {
    // Which of those will work, which is the best practice,
    //what are pros and cons
    this.dependency1.get();
    this.dependency2.get();
    this.dependency3.get();
  }
}
```

So based on this example:

1. Is version 1 (Dependency1) equivalent to version 2 (Dependeny2)? Or is version 1 only for TypeScript without any relevance for injection?
2. Is this line of code

   this.dependency2 = dependency2;

necessary of will this be done "automagically" like assumed for Dependency3?

3. What is Injectable doing exactly? How would the answer to questions 1 and 2 differ without it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing up typescript *parameter properties* and the Angular2 DI mechanic.

Basically you have two options when defining constructors with typescript. The short version:

```
@Component()
class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    public dependency1: Dependency1, 
    public dependency2: Dependency2, 
    public dependency3: Dependency3
  ) { }

  // [...]
```

Which will be transformed into the longer, more verbose version you can also use:

```
@Component()
class MyComponent {
  public dependency1: Dependency1;
  public dependency2: Dependency2;
  public dependency3: Dependency3;

  constructor(
    dependency1: Dependency1, 
    dependency2: Dependency2, 
    dependency3: Dependency3
  ) {
    this.dependency1 = dependency1;
    this.dependency2 = dependency2;
    this.dependency3 = dependency3;
  }

  // [...]
```

This is explained in the [Typescript Handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Classes.md#parameter-properties).
Both have their pro & cons, the longer version is more understandable and clear for people new to typescript, while the later saves quite some typing, so choose your poison. :)

**Notice:** You don't need the @Injectable() decorator if your class already has another decorator, it only serves to force meta-data generation by typescript, which it only does for decorated classes to prevent bloating transpiled code with unnecessary meta-data.

---

Regarding the DI mechanic, assuming you imported definitions and for Dependency1, Dependency2 and Dependency3 (1), registered their providers (2) and `angular` created an instance of your component (3):

- Inside `someFunction()` `this.dependency1` is a declared (as public at the start of your class) and has a defined type (`Dependency1`) for all typescript cares. But its current value is `undefined`, since it has not been assigned a value in the constructor (or anywhere else).

  **Fix** Add `dependency1: Dependency1` parameter to the constructor and assign `this.dependency1 = dependency1` or use the typescript short-hand above ([**EDIT**] `constructor(public dependency1, ...`).
- Accessing `this.dependency2` inside the constructor should raise a compile-error, since `MyComponent` has no property `dependency2`. In the unlikely case this does compile/transpile then `this.dependency2` should have the correct value, althought you will not have type information for `this.dependency2` (*bad*).

  **Fix:** Add a declaration for `this.dependency2` to your component, eg. add `public dependency2: Dependency2;` above the constructor [**EDIT**] or add the `public` property in front of the constructors `dependency2` parameter, `constructor(public dependency2, ...`).
- Last but not least `this.dependency3` has both of the above problems, no declaration (like `dependency2`) and `undefined` as values (like `dependency1`).

  **Fix:** See above. ;)

**Note:** It is important to understand the difference between [declaration & definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) (*This is about C++, but applies to typescript as well*) for this and I hope I did not mix up terms while typping. ;)

---

1. Done for example via:

   ```
   import { Dependency1 } from 'dependency-module-1';
   import { Dependency2 } from 'dependency-module-2';
   import { Dependency3 } from 'dependency-module-3';
   ```
2. There are multiple ways to define providers for your dependencies

   - During bootrap. This makes the modules available (via their providers) to each and every component in your app.

     ```
     bootstrap(AppComponent, [
       Dependency1,
       Dependency2,
       Dependency3
     ]);
     ```
   - With the component decorator. This makes the modules available to MyComponent and **the same module instance** to each child-component.
     If a child component hovever has its own provider array, a **new** module instance is generated for it (and like above **shared** with all child components). Recommended reading material is the [official Angular2 guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) and [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) blog post. Here is the example:

     ```
     @Component({
       providers: [
         Dependency1,
         Dependency2,
         Dependency3
       ]
     })
     class MyComponent {
       \\ [...]
     ```
3. Either MyComponent is the one passed as (first) parameter for angulars bootstrap method or the components selector is used somewhere in your DOM.

---

Regarding best practices, you could try using [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) and the awesome [custom-rule-plugins](https://github.com/palantir/tslint#custom-rules), eg. the codealyze one is angular-specific.

Last but not least there is also the official Angular Typescript [Styleguide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html). ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. However, I am not sure regarding "Accessing this.dependency2 inside the constructor...": From my understanding this contradicts what you said about the short version that gets transformed into the longer version. Or do I miss something?

Comment: It would work with `constructor(public dependency2: Dependency2, dependency3: Dependency3)`, note the added `public` parameter property for dependency2. When you declase `dependency1` at the top of MyComponent, adding `public` is optional, but the 'constructor expansion' only happens when you **explicitly** add a public/private modifier, only those parameters (with public/private modifier) get expanded. (*This is why the short version can be less readable for people new to typescript*)

Comment: Sorry, I added this piece of information to my original answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at official [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Also have a look at this [blog](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html)

Angular is based on [constructor based dependency injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/). 
In short that means constructor parameters  are injected as dependency.
`Car(e:Engine)`

Then engine will be inject by DI in car instance.

Now all your code is Typescript ways of defining a constructor. Following 2 code are equivalent.

`e: Engine 
   Car(e:Engine){
      this.e = e 
    }`

`Car(public e:Engine){ }`

Comment: i have read both, and numerous others (maybe thats the problem), best practice, procs/cons still not clear

Comment: The official precisely describe how it should be.